# Is there a pre-defined function for conduit analogy of `takeWhile`?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I find the following function missing from the [`Data.Conduit.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.5.1/docs/Data-Conduit-List.html) module, and I couldn't find an easy way to compose this using functions in that module.

```
takeWhile :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> Consumer a m [a]
takeWhile p = await >>= \case
                Nothing -> return []
                Just b  -> if p b
                  then (b :) <$> takeWhile p
                  else (leftover b) >> return []
```

This function is very useful in my application where I sometimes need to group the next few items together, and I am not sure how many are there.

The missing of this function is kind of strange to me as there are `take :: Monad m => Int -> Consumer a m [a]`, and `groupBy :: Monad m => (a -> a -> Bool) -> Conduit a m [a]`, but no `takeWhile`.

Am I missing something?

---

**Edit:** Per @ErikR's request, here is two simple examples that can perhaps clarify why I think this function could be useful.

Case 1: the protocol specifies there be a header section in the stream. For simplicity let's assume it's a `String` stream and the header items are marked by a leading `@`.

Stream content:

```
@language=English
@encoding=Unicode
Apple
Orange
Blue
Red
Sheep
Dog
...
```

Code using `takeWhile`:

```
myConduit :: Conduit String IO String ()
myConduit = do
    headers <- takeWhile ((== '@') . head)
    awaitForever $ \ item -> do
        case getLanguage headers of
            English -> ...
            French  -> ...
```

Case 2: the protocol specifies that items with prefix `@` has several continuations prefixed by `+`.

Stream content:

```
Apple
Orange
Blue
@Has
+kell
@A
+Really
+Long
+Word
Dog
...
```

Code using `takeWhile`:

```
myConduit :: Conduit String IO String ()
myConduit = runMaybeC . forever $ do
    a <- maybe (lift mzero) return =<< await
    aConts <- if head item == '@' then takeWhile ((== '+') . head)
                                  else return []
    liftIO . putStrLn . concat $ a : aConts
```

However, aside from being useful, it is also for completeness.  I see that `Data.Conduit.List`'s goal is to provide a set of "list-like" operations in the Conduit context. I think bread-and-butter functions like `takeWhile` should be provided, along with its siblings like `dropWhile`, so that people don't have to change their style of coding when thinking about conduits as lists.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you use your `takeWhile`?

Comment: @ErikR: For example, the stream has a header section where certain number of items that have a particular flag should be treated separately.

Comment: Seeing how you use it with other combinators to parse out that header would be helpful.

Comment: @ErikR: Another example is when the protocol specifies a special item which can indicate that several coming items are its continuations. `A -> B -> C-many -> C.1 -> C.2 -> C.3 -> D -> E ...`

Comment: Do you have any _code_ you can share? I'm willing to spend time looking into the problem, but it would really help to see some actual use cases.

Comment: @ErikR: I updated the question and provided the two examples I described above. Thank you for your time!

Comment: conduit-combinators defines a takeWhile, but with a slightly different type signature. Your desired behavior can come from `takeWhile f =$ consume`

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman: It seems that conduit-combinators doesn't have an equivalent of `groupBy`. Is this a conscious decision?

Comment: No, feel free to open a PR.